# Select element closes immediately when clicked in Chrome (Some Android devices)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, shopify, facebook-pixel

I have a page with a select option that automatically closes when clicked on some mobile devices (Chrome/Android). This problem does not occur on the desktop nor when I debug in chrome as mobile.
It's a Shopify site, coded with the language "liquid", which basically is html.

After some days testing, I discovered thats the issue is happening because of some compatibilities problems with the Facebook Pixels code, and my page, thats refreshing and closes my select. After that I ve tryed some JS solutions to stop this event occurs like event.preventDefault(); and event.stopPropagation(), but not worked.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="selector-wrapper js product-form__item">
  <label for="SingleOptionSelector-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">{{ option.name }}</label>
  <select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-{{ section.id }} product-form__input"
    id="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}" data-name="{{ option.name }}" data-index="option{{ forloop.index }}">
    {% for value in option.values %}
    <option value="{{ value | escape }}" {% if option.selected_value==value %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>{{ value
      }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('SingleOptionSelector-0').onmouseup=function(e) {e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();};
</script>
```

I have tried everything and Googled everything I could for several days and can't find a solution.
Any ideias?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to share the URL to test it on mobile, otherwise hard to figure out what happens actaully

Comment: Any updates on this? I just recently ran into the same issue.

Comment: Just additional info on my issue, I ran into this bug on a react website. But verified that this also happens for android chrome on other websites (e.g. w3schools page for select tag).

Answer (score 0):

if it helps anyone:

in Wordpress/woocommerce with WpRocket and PixelYourSite plugin:
in our case was same problem and solution was excluding public.js from Delay JavaScript execution: pixelyoursite-pro/dist/scripts/public.js

Hope it helps,

A

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I am unable to solve it but here is a test page to see the issue: (View the link in Chrome on an Android mobile device)

"link removed"

Comment: Also note that removing only one item in the test page and the dropdown works fine, for instance, there are 8 hidden input fields. Remove just one of them and it works. Remove the Meta Pixel code and it works. Does look like it is a bug in Chrome, but a workaround will be most helpful.

Comment: What worked for me in the end (since I am using Jquery mobile) was to use  data-role="none" attribute in the select element.